# Chrome bold fonts are very large?

Tags: google-chrome, windows-8.1, fonts

These fonts are so big and ugly. The only thing I can think of that could have caused this is:
The other day some of my desktop icons were the placeholder white page, I used "Windows Shortcut Arrow Editor" (x64) to change to classic shortcut arrows and then back again, which repaired my icons. Then this happened.

[image]

Also, if I mouse over one of these links, the blue underline is broken where the bolded text is.

The only other things I can think might be affecting this are possibly Stardocks's Fences, Start8, or ModernMix apps, though I doubt it as they've been on this PC for weeks at least. Also, I do have the DPI and ClearType set up already. This just began occurring out of the blue. I also tried resetting font settings to default both in Chrome and the Control Panel.

Comment: have you tried reinstalling Chrome itself?

Comment: Yes I have already re-installed Chrome - twice, even - once before and after removing possible culprits.

Comment: Not a duplicate. Issue has been resolved, not related to DPI or DirectWrite. EVGA PrecisionX 16 broke a font, it had to be reinstalled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have also been having this issue recently. I'm not sure how long this has been the case, but apparently DirectWrite has been enabled by default. I disabled it by navigating to `chrome://flags/#disable-direct-write` and clicking enable (enabling the disable). This solved the problem for me.

Edit:

Actually, although this does fix it, it may not be preferable because the fonts don't quite look normal. I found out that my problem actually comes from EVGA PrecisionX 16 which I installed the other day. If this is your problem, you have to reinstall one of your fonts. The easiest way I found was to go into your command prompt, and type `copy C:\Windows\Fonts\arialbd.ttf <destination folder>`. If you are on Windows 7, then use `arialbd_0.ttf` instead. Then navigate to that folder, click on it, and install it, saying ok to whatever prompt appears. This fixed the issue for me and I have re enabled DirectWrite.

Comment: I did not think of that at all, I did also install PrecisionX 16 just before this occurred. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

One of those programs you mentioned definitely could cause a change in font since that is their intentions. Start9 and ModernMix could be your culprets.  Also double check on your chrome font manually too. It seems like you are using a nonstandard font which would cause what you are describing.  If your Chrome font seems normal then try disabling/ uninstalling the other two programs to see if there is any change.  If that still doesn't work then reinstall those two programs and Chrome itself too.

Comment: I'll try removing the Stardock apps, but I've already reinstalled Chrome, and I'm not using any non-standard fonts. Will report back with results.

Edit: Just uninstalled all three Stardock programs and rebooted. No dice. Will try reinstalling Chrome again now.

Comment: I know Fences would definitely not affect it.

Comment: Well, now I've: uninstalled the Stardock programs, rebooted, reinstalled Chrome, and still no change. I think I may have to go back to a restore point. That'll be lame if so, considering I've been re-downloading my Steam library today...